# Bounds involving exponential

Tags: analysis, limits, inequality, algorithms, exponential-function

I know that $(1+(1/n))^n \to e$ and $(1-(1/n))^n \to 1/e$ as $n \to \infty$.

Both these sequences are increasing. I saw this by plotting; **is there an analytical way to see this?** Taking the derivative of $(1+(1/x))^x$ or $x \log (1+1/x)$ gets messy and ends up with a quantity $\log((x+1)/x)-\frac{1}{x+1}$ that I don't know what to do with.

I would like lower bounds on $1+(1/n)$ and $1-(1/n)$ using the exponential. If we don't use the above observation that the sequences are increasing, we have $1+(1/n) \ge e^{1/(2n)}$ for all large $n$ and $(1-(1/n))^{-1} \ge e^{1/(2n)}$ for all large $n$, which basically follow from $e>e^{1/2}$.

However, if we use the fact that $(1-(1/n))^n$ is increasing to $e^{-1}$, I think we also have $(1-(1/n))^{-1} \ge e^{1/n}$ for all $n \ge 1$.

**I am wondering what are the strongest statements of the above flavor that we can state (regarding lower bounds for $1+(1/n)$ and $1-(1/n)$).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need derivatives or the binomial theorem or lengthy techniques.

By [the AM-GM inequality](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean_Inequality) we have:

$$ 1\cdot\underbrace{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot\ldots\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}_{n \text{ times}}< \left[\frac{1+n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n+1}\right]^{n+1}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\tag{1}$$
and that proves that the sequence given by $a_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is increasing.

In a similar way we may prove that the sequence given by $b_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}=\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{-(n+1)}$ is decreasing. The claim follows.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any perspective on my other question regarding lower bounds of the form $1+(1/n) \ge e^{1/(2n)}$ for all large $n$?

Comment: @angryavian: if $x\in[0,\alpha]$, we have $e^x\leq 1+ \frac{e^\alpha-1}{\alpha} x$ since $e^x$ is a convex function.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have a video that explains why $(1+(1/n))^n$ is monotonic increasing, and it doesn't require taking any derivatives. You can similarly prove the second sequence is increasing, the video is here :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgu-MOQlhYQ

It's a bit lengthy, but feel free to skip any bits that are obvious/you already know.

For a TLDR explanation, I encourage you to write out $(1+(1/n))^n$ as a summation using the binomial theorem, and then compare $(1+(1/n))^n$ with $(1+(\frac{1}{n+1}))^{n+1}$

Comment: The video I linked you to is actually part of a series on Euler's number, the other parts of the series may answer your other questions regarding it as well.

Comment: Thank you, I understand that part now. I don't think the same technique would work for $(1-(1/n))^n$ though... does it?

Comment: Are you referring to the technique used in the video?

Comment: Yes. In that case, minus signs are introduced in the summations.

Comment: I have just realized there may be a simpler way to do it. Take the natural logarithm of $(1 - \frac{1}{n})^n$ and take the natural logarithm of $(1 - \frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}$ . Now use the properties of logarithm. We are now comparing $log(1 - \frac{1}{n})^n$ and $log(1 - \frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}$ . Bring both exponents down using the properties of logarithms. Now use the fact that the natural logarithm is an increasing function. That should complete the proof.